# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function in Laravel application (Bootstrap 4 preset)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, bootstrap-4

I am building an application with the PHP framework Laravel. I am using the [Bootstrap 4 preset](https://laravel-news.com/bootstrap-4-laravel-preset) and installed a fresh project. Everything is working fine, css, and even the dropdown menu you get from the navbar. But for some reason, I get a Typerror in my console when I try to initatlize the tooltip by doing [this](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#example-enable-tooltips-everywhere). Also tried to initalize the tooltip by a tooltip class but that doesn't seem to work either. I got the same problem with the popover component.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
>
> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function

I've changed nothing in the JS, except deleting the comments you get from a Laravel installation.

bootstrap.js

```
window._ = require('lodash');

//Popper for Jquery/Bootstrap
window.Popper = require('popper.js/dist/umd/popper');

//Jquery for Bootstrap
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery/dist/jquery.slim');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

//Axios for AJAX Calls
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

app.js

```
//Bootstrap application with dependencies
require('./bootstrap');

//Import Vue
window.Vue = require('vue');

//Vue components
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

//Vue init
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});

//Tooltip init
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

HTML/Blade

```
<i class="ion-help-circled" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Dit is het adres waarop de website staat tijdens de testfase"></i>
```

Also tried to include the tooltip init below the regular scripts in my blade file, but again, doesn't seem to work.

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script>

$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
});

</script>
```

It seems that it is a problem with popper.js I guess, because it applies to both the tooltip and the popover component.

Comment: put `//Tooltip init
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})` staticly in your script tags

Comment: Already tried that, see my last paragraph. I will edit my post because I think it's not clear enough what I mean.

Comment: Are you calling the function after bootstrap has load completely ?

Comment: Try using the esm version rather than umd.

Comment: @btl Can you show me an example? Laravel did this for a reason I guess..

Comment: There should be a directory alongside `umd/` in the popper directory in node modules . `popper.js/dist/umd/popper` change that too `popper.js/dist/esm/popper`

Comment: @btl sorry for the late answer but that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: use this $('body').tooltip({
            selector: '.tooltip-viewport-top'
    });

Comment: @Bugfixer What must this do? because I got still the same problem.

Comment: jQueryUI should be included in order to use the `tooltip()` method. See https://jsfiddle.net/cnjeszng/ . Note: jQuery instead of jQuery Slim is used.

Comment: @GuyT You know that tooltip is a bootstrap component? jQueryUI is not included with Bootstrap.

Comment: @Gijsberts sorry, missed that. No problems at all: https://jsfiddle.net/cnjeszng/2/ . Are you sure you are loading your dependencies the right way?

Comment: @GuyT I am using the Laravel framework with the Bootstrap 4 preset so actually I don't know for sure, but I guess it's a wide problem from the preset itself because I was not the only one with this problem. Also created an issue on github.

Comment: @Gijsberts What if you use `new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  mounted: function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  }
})
` so you are sure the HTML is rendered?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try instead

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery'); // <-- main, not 'slim'
window.Popper = require('popper.js');
require('bootstrap');
```

The "slim" jQuery dist excludes some features, necessary to register correctly `tooltip` as a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the issue is that `tooltip()` has not *always existed in jQuery UI*.  It was added in version 1.9...

> version added: 1.9 (Source: **[API.jQueryUI.com: Tooltip Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/)**.)

If you don't have a version of jQuery UI at version 1.9 or higher, you'll get the error: `tooltip() is not a function()`.